# How to display an image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

Well, I just downloaded a free template from the internet and had this at a lower level of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhJIq.jpg .

Instead of the map, I want to place an image there, but I can't figure out how to do it. There is a very complex script used for the map, has like 2000-2500 lines. I tried erasing everything and placing my script instead of it, but in the best case, my image was shown after the footer.

The thing that makes it darker is this code, I think:

```
    #map {
    height: 830px;
}
.map {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.contact {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 830px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -830px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.51);
}
.contact-caption {
    margin-top: 120px;
}
```

In the index, it looks something like this:

```
<div class="api-map" id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 map" id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this in your css.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("imageURL");
}
```

Alternatively if you must use javascript for the background image do this.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't thought of that. Here's the link (uploaded to mediafire, the original website required you to create an account): http://www.mediafire.com/download/b2idik2em7my983/doctor-responsive-html-template_%281%29.zip .  What I want to change is the map at "Contact". The thing you suggested before didn't seem to work..

Comment: Okay I took a look at that template shapebootstrap.net site. That is a single page website with multiple sections, You need to edit that particular section.  This will work .contact{background-image: url: ("imageURL")}

Comment: Well, that should work but I can't find where to put it. I placed it in the style.css but it gave me either a grey or white background, but not my image. I also can't find the resolution my image should be. If you could help me, I'd be grateful!

Comment: If you want to remove the map, look closely at your HTML and you will see the following <!-- map section --> the div under that contains all of the html for the map that is displaying. In your css there is also a section under /*gmap*/ under there is the styling for the map. You should be able to remove all of that and put the css I mentioned above in your .contact{} css and have the functionality you want.

Comment: in styles.css there is a specific part designed to style the contact section of your html. It looks like this .contact{} that is where you should place background-image: url: ("imageURL"). Also you might want to go ahead and remove references to the map in your html, css, and js. I mentioned a few above. A lot of the script tags you have are googlemap.js files that all work to make that map work in that contact section.

Comment: No, still not working. I hope I don't ask for too much, but could you do it for me and give me the code I need to change? With a random image?

Comment: I have tested the way I mentioned that didnt work for you and verified that it works. I have also tested this way and verified that it works, though it is not the most effiecient way, but hopefully you can understand this method.

Comment: For some reason it inserted an extra semicolon when I pasted: should look like this. <div class="api-map" id="contact"> <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"> <!-- CHANGE THE BACKGROUND IMAGE BELLOW --> <div class="col-md-12 map" id="map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; background-image: url('tipue.com/img/jetty.jpg');"></div></div></div> </div> 

On my end this works alone, but if you still have trouble try removing all of the script tags with a reference to the google maps api. Otherwise all the solution I provided work for me and you have some other issue.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to ask if you have any additional issues.

Comment: Actually, I accidentally removed the animation that slides you through the website when you use the top menu, now it's all crisp, like pressing the button and "teleporting" you instead of sliding. Do you have any idea how could I fix this...?

Comment: This is controlled in the custom.js file located in the js folder. There is a section with a comment above it that reads //this code is for smooth scroll and nav selector. Make sure they section is still there and if it is not you will need to make a copy of the additional download and put it there. Also make sure smoothscroll.js is still in your folder. Additionaly if you made any changes to a tags that could cause the issue. Each tag should have a href to a section id. Also just an FYI if your original question has been answered make it as such, and upvote any helpful comments.

Comment: So I don't really know why that function is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This question would be easier to answer if you had provided the actual template for me to reference. However, try the following steps:

1. Find the root element that contains the map as a background.
2. Delete the map from it, and use the following css:

   ```
   element{
       background-image: url("imageUrl");
   }
   ```

That will style the background nicely. If you need further help, please comment on this post or clarify!

Comment: I tried what CodeBroJohn said and my image appeared, but extended to the other field there. Here's the theme: http://www.mediafire.com/download/b2idik2em7my983/doctor-responsive-html-template_%281%29.zip . I want to change the map on the background, at "Contact".

Comment: Interestingly, the `.contact` class that it seems to be creating the map on doesn't respond to a background image thing... strange. I'll have to investigate this better once I get home to a text editor.